# How to « reverse » inheritance when working with polymorphism?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a working design in C++, just like the following :

```
struct E {
    int some_properties ;
    // … some more
};

class A {
    public:
        void tick() {
            std::swap(futur, past) ;
        }

        void do_something() {
            // do something (read past, write futur)
            futur->some_properties = past->some_properties + 1 ;
        }

        E* past ;
   protected:
        E* futur ;
};
```

Now, I'd like to both create a `class B` which inherit `class A` with a new `void do_other_thing()` method and a `struct F` which inherit `struct E` with a new `int some_other ;` attribute.

The method `void do_other_thing()` could be for example :

```
void do_other_thing() {
    // do something (read past, write futur)
    futur->some_properties = past->some_properties + past->some_other ;
    futur->some_other = past->some_other + 1 ;
}
```

**I'm very confused about how to achieve this inheritance.**

Especially when it comes to achieve this kind of use case :

```
// A a ;
a.tick() ;
a.do_something() ;
```

And :

```
// B b ;
b.tick()
b.do_something() ;
b.tick() ;
b.do_other_thing() ;
```

Here comes the question :

- **Is this even possible ?**
- **If yes, how ?**
- **If not, how to solve the problem with a better stucture ?**

EDIT:

As answered, the simplest inheritance pattern will be:

```
class B : public A {
    void do_other_thing(){ // Something }
}

struct F : public E {
    int some_other;
}
```

The problem encountered is that `past` and `futur` here are `E` pointers:

```
void do_other_thing() {
    // do something (read past, write futur)
    futur->some_properties = past->some_properties + past->some_other ;
    futur->some_other = past->some_other + 1 ;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's stopping you from inheriting in those two cases?

Comment: Why do you think is not even possible ?

Comment: Could you make clearer where you are specifically stuck with the inheritance. Best would be to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Side note: solving the problem with a better structure would require a description of the problem that your solution is intended to solve.

Comment: Few constraints has been implicit in my question. The problem were about « reversing » the inheritance back in `do_other_thing`, as I store only a `E` pointer and I have to access both `E` and `F` attributes. I wasn't used to `dynamic_cast`, which solves the problem. (Do I have to explicit the extra constraints as the problem is solved ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `dynamic_cast`:

```
void do_other_thing() {
    F* futur_f = dynamic_cast<F*>(futur);
    F* past_f = dynamic_cast<F*>(past);
    assert(futur_f && past_f);
    futur_f->some_properties = past_f->some_properties + past_f->some_other ;
    futur_f->some_other = past_f->some_other + 1 ;
}
```

or you could use a second pair of pointer members in `B` which point to the same objects as `futur` and `past` (more data, less casting - essentially caching the runtime cast)

or you could use a template base class where the type of `past` and `futur` is a template parameter (sometimes requires the introduction of a non-templated "root class" and making everything virtual).

And probably quite a few other ways, with varying trade-offs, benefits, and complications.

What to choose depends on the rest of your program and your personal preferences.

Comment: For my purpose, `dynamic_cast` seems legit.
Thanks !

Comment: ( A second pair of pointers members will not do the trick, as a huge inheritance tree will pollute my classes with members caching the runtime cast.

A template base class with the type of `past` and `futur` as template parameter will prevent polymorphism, for example in the context of a `std::vector<A*>`)

Answer (score 0):

First, yes it is possible. The following is just pseudo-code for illustration:

```
class B : public A {
    void do_other_thing(){ std::cout << "Other" << std::endl; }
}

struct F : public E {
    int some_other;
}
```

Now both of these new types will follow the principle of being able to take the place of their parent types. This is achieved by referring to the sub-types by a pointer to their base types (polymorphism).

```
std::shared_ptr<A> baseARefToB{ std::make_shared<B>() };
baseRefToB->do_something();

std::shared_ptr<E> baseERefToF{ std::make_shared<F>() };
baseERefToF->some_properties = 3;
```

Note that I cannot access their sub-class methods and properties via the base class references. BUT:

```
std::static_pointer_cast<B>(baseRefToB)->do_other_thing(); 
std::static_pointer_cast<E>(baseERefToF)->some_other = 42;
```

Here I have cast the references to their base types so I can access their sub-class specific functionality.

So from your problem description you will be able (always) to call the base class functionality (`do_something` and `some_properties`) for all types of `A` and `E`, but you will only be able to access the sub-class functionality if you refer to the object via pointers with the correct type.